# NFC - FPGA - TFT Question

Tags: fpga, nfc, tft

Im working on an idea but am having a problem finding even a starting point for research. 
The idea is to have images (video) sent over NFC to a NFC connected to FPGA (or something else could do?) and display those images to, let's say PSP TFT.

Any general ideas from where to start researching this ? Im not expecting a complete solution just a nudge in the right direction. Could this be done, what is the minimal (cheapest) board that could do this ? Ive seen PSP screens driven with fpga but they are all $40+ units. Any cheaper options ? Does it even need to be FPGA?

Thank you

Comment: I don't think this has anything to do with this site, this question is about ideas of finding products, and not a technical question.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Using an FPGA for this task seems to be overkill. Yes, you can connect a display to an FPGA, but you can do that with lots of microprocessors as well. Development in software is also much faster.

So unless you want to design in the FPGA for the learning experience or you already have an FPGA with some free space in your design I would go with some cheap Cortex-M3 CPU board.

Regarding NFC, yes, sure. You can use NFC to transmit images. But keep in mind that you will have a data-rate of about 2 kilobytes/second under ideal conditions. So transmitting images takes quite a while. You can cheat a little and just use NFC just to detect the transmit event and do bluetooth or wifi paring for the real data. That's what Samsung did for their S-Beam feature on several Android phones.

Regarding NFC chips: Most of them are rather complex beasts when it comes to program them. Also the data-sheets are rarely publicly available. 
The PN532 from NXP is a bit aged but you can actually buy the chip and get data-sheets for it. There is also plenty of example source-code out there, so you don't have to start from scratch. If you don't have prior experiences with NFC, that would be my recommendation.